# Integral $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a\frac{x^n} {x^n+1}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Please help me find the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a\frac{x^n} {x^n+1}\,\mathrm dx$, $a>0$. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: For $a<1,$ it is equal to $a.$ I can't say for $a\ge 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution without Dominated convergence theorem.

- For $0 < a < 1$ we have
  $$\int_0^a \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx \le \int_0^a a^n\,dx = a^{n+1} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$
- For $a = 1$ and arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0 $ we have
  $$0 \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx = \int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx + \int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx\le (1-\varepsilon)^{n+1} + \varepsilon \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \varepsilon$$
  so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx \in [0,\varepsilon]$. Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx = 0$.
- For $a \ge 1$ we have
  \begin{align}
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx + \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^a \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx\\
  &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^a \left(1-\frac1{1+x^n}\right)\,dx\\
  &= a-1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^a \frac{dx}{1+x^n}
  \end{align}
  and we claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^a \frac{dx}{1+x^n} = 0$. We have
  \begin{align}
  \int_1^a \frac{dx}{1+x^n} &= \int_1^{1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}} \frac{dx}{1+x^n} + \int_{1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}}^a \frac{dx}{1+x^n} \\
  &\le \int_1^{1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}} dx + \int_{1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}}^a \frac{dx}{1+\left(1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n}\\
  &= \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{a-1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\left(1+\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n}\\
  &\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0
  \end{align}
  so we conclude $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx  =a-1.$$

Comment: Thank you! I've understood it. However I don't know how I'd be able to have a similar ideea as you had for the calculus of $ \int_1^a $. Anyways, I'm really thankful for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to solve this problem. Note that 
\begin{equation}
0 \leq \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} \leq 1
\end{equation}
for all values $0 \leq x \leq a$. For any $0 \leq x < 1$ we have
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} = 0
\end{equation}
while for $1 < x$ we have
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} = 1.
\end{equation}
By the Dominated Convergence Theorem therefore
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^a \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} dx = \max(a - 1, 0). 
\end{equation}
Alternatively you could use the fact that if a sequence of integrable functions $f_n:[0, a] \to \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to $f$ then 
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^a f_n(x) dx = \int_0^a f(x) dx.
\end{equation}
Note that the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions must be continuous. We've seen above that the limit function is $\mathbb{I}(x > 1) + \frac 12 \mathbb{I}(x = 0.5)$ which is not continuous on $[0, a]$ unless $a < 1$. Assuming that $a \geq 1$, this suggests that we decompose the integral as
\begin{equation}
\int_0^a \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} dx + \int_1^a \frac{x^n}{x^n + 1} dx.
\end{equation}
Can you show that both of these integrals converge using uniform convergence?

Comment: But the convergence is not uniform if $a>1$. However it's possible to split the interval.

Comment: I know nothing about dominated convergence theorem, therefore I can't really use it.

Comment: Do you know about uniform convergence of functions? If so you could use the approach I outlined in my answer.

Comment: Never heard of that aswell...

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on positive $x$ values. If $x$ is less than one, then $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n} +1} =0.$$
However if $x$ is greater than one, $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n} +1} =1.$$
And if $x=1$, $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n} +1} =\frac{1}{1+1}=1/2.$$
Therefore if we let $f:\left\{\mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{0\}\right\}\rightarrow [ 0,1)$; $f(x)=\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n} +1}$, then:$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } f( x) =\begin{Bmatrix}
0 & \text{if} \ \ x< 1\\
1 & \text{if} \ \ x >1\\
1/2 & \text{if} \ \ x=1
\end{Bmatrix}$$
Therefore $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\int ^{a}_{0} f( x) =a-1.$$

Comment: I don't understand... How does the limit of the function helps me find $$ \int_0^a f(x) $$ or $$\lim{ \int_0^a f(x)} $$?